# Which is latest Business Desktop Deployment version?

Tags: deployment, mdt

I used Business Desktop Deployment (BDD) to build my project. Scripts are written in python. The BDD I am having doesn't support Visual Studio 2008. 
Please tell me what is the latest version of BDD which supports VS2008
where I can get more info about Business Desktop Deployment?

Comment: You could at least say what BDD stands for. I'm pretty sure Google isn't giving me the right results for ["bdd"](http://www.google.com/search?q=bdd).

Comment: I get 'behavior driven development', but even on StackOverflow, all the 'BDD' questions don't actually specify what it is. Am I out of the loop? Also please specify what exactly your BDD here means, and what library/module/whatever it is you have that's in Python?

Comment: @birryree: I guess this is where tag wikis could come in handy.

Comment: I've changed the tags and your post to be more clear what you are looking for. Most of the BDD-tagged questions on SO are related to Behavior Driven Design as @Lunivore and @BoltClock said. Also see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

BDD is a mini-methodology related to acceptance testing and TDD (it does stuff higher up, but this is probably what you're doing).

From your question, it looks like you've been writing BDD scenarios or unit examples in Python. Visual Studio isn't a great tool for writing Python in. If you want to carry on in Python, try Vim, or you might be able to get a Python plugin for Eclipse or IntelliJ.

If you want to use Visual Studio to program, use C# or F#. There are a couple of great BDD frameworks - [SpecFlow](http://specflow.org/) or [TickSpec](http://www.trelford.com/blog/post/TickSpec.aspx) - which can help you.

More information, including a list of tools, is available on [the Wikipedia page on BDD.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior_driven_development)

Otherwise, please clarify your problem. It doesn't make huge sense in its current form!

**Edit**: Well, I learn something new every day. BDD also stands for "Business Desktop Deployment", and is a Microsoft product. [Here's a page with an update](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=02A2605D-51E8-469F-BE4A-1DD2AF580502&displaylang=en) suggesting you should use Microsoft Development Toolkit. Hope that points you in the right direction. I imagine the tool we've been using, [click-once](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28VS.80%29.aspx), does something similar.

You should probably know that few people seem to recognise BDD as meaning anything other than Behaviour Driven Development in software these days. I've heard Binary Decision Diagram as well; not often though. Good luck in your search.

Comment: Actually, I am migrationg from VS .Net 2003 to VS .Net 2008, I am using few .lib files created by BDD to build the project. but its giving linking errors becoz the .lib files created by BDD are not compatible with VS 2008. So I want the new version of BDD which will create VS 2008 compatible libraries.

Comment: @Sanjay: It doesn't make sense to have old and new versions of behavior-driven development, which Lunivore is talking about. What is this BDD you are referring to?

Comment: In my case BDD is Business Desktop Deployment kit for generating External Micosoft Projects.

Answer (score 1):

There's an article [here](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/rtrent/archive/2009/03/07/business-desktop-deployment-bdd-and-microsoft-deployment-toolkit-mdt-that-have-been-retired.aspx) that might help you with Business Desktop Deployment (BDD) versions. It's dated March 2009 and says:

> Microsoft Deployment Toolkit 2008 Update 1 replaces all prior versions of MDT and BDD. It provides additional support for new OS versions and deployment scenarios and is the upgrade path for users of earlier versions.

The article points to the [MDT 2010 download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=3bd8561f-77ac-4400-a0c1-fe871c461a89&displaylang=en&tm).